# Strange space between element with border radius and it's absolute positioned pseudo content

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

I've got a problem on IE10 regarding an element with border radius and its absolute positioned pseudo content.

So, HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="border">
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#parent {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

}
#border {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: gray;
    position: relative;
}
#border:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Rendering on Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Rendering on IE10:

[image: IE10]

Here's the [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2QVSv/1/).

Can anyone help me solve the mystery?

Thank you!

TESTED ON: 3 different machines with Windows 7 and IE10.

Comment: I've tested the fiddle in IE 10 and it looks the same to what Chrome renders. sorry.

Comment: I've tested on 3 different machines and all had the same problem.

Comment: It looks the same for me across FF, Chrome, and IE.

Comment: @PAdrian here is the snapshot on my side: http://i.imgur.com/gGdRdmB.png

Comment: tested with Windows 8 and IE10 : similar as Chrome, have you tried a clear cache ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using IE11 (tested in IE10 as well) for this fiddle and yes I see a tiny little white space on both, and rendering good on FF.

change your `left:100%` to `left:99.9%`

[image: IE10 with left:100% and white space]

[image: IE10 with left:99.9% and NO white space]

Comment: I'm using 11 also and I *don't* see the line. Odd.

Comment: well I see :/ and tested in IE10 (updated answer) and keep seeing the white space.

Comment: The problem is very annoying. In the real situation I have a image instead of the green element and I have discovered that the space is all around the gray element. This means that the height of the gray element will be lower than the image.

Comment: make a fiddle with real content, so we can real help you with this IE stupid problem.

Answer (score 0):

One work colleague solve the problem.
He added:

```
border-right: 1px solid transparent;
```

Here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/2QVSv/8/).

Thank you all!